# Creating a dynamic pop-up modal with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a Service to manage all of the different pop-up modals that will be used in my application. So far everything is going well except for having the ability to update the position of the modal on the screen every time it comes into view.

Here is my **UPDATED** directive

```
app.directive('skModal', function($window){
   return {
      restrict:'EA',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           var top, left;

           scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function(newVal){
               if(newVal) {
                   top = ($window.innerHeight - elem.outerHeight()) / 2;
                   left = ($window.innerWidth - elem.outerWidth()) / 2;

                   elem.css({ 'top': top, 'left': left });
               }
           });

       }
   } ;
});
```

I simply use ng-include to populate any template I wish into the modal, then I use `$watch` to check when the `ngShow` variable is flipped.  The problem is that my `elem` DOM element is not IN the DOM at the time, so the `outerHeight()` and `outerWidth()` functions return 0

Comment: When you say it's not in the DOM - is it actually disconnected entirely or is it `display: none`?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it is in the DOM. it is just `display:none;`.. I was able to fix this by instead of using ng-hide/ng-show I simply change the left and top values to be -9999. That way the element is always in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you should used angular.element,

> angular.element(element).prop('offsetHeight');

You will give the same result

Angular.element does NOT support outerHeight() and height() ;)

Comment: It does support it if I have jQuery included in my project though..  I was able to get the error to go away, but the problem is that the element is not in the DOM at the time of the `$watch` event so the `elem.outerHeight() = 0`

Comment: An alternative would be to define three prerecorded sizes taking into account the size of the screen. (small, medium, large) used CSS media queries with % width .large .medium .small apply to your modal.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your comment that you fixed your issue with a large offset.

In case you want a different solution, you could also try removing `ng-hide` just before you take your measurement. Given that `ngShow` has just flipped, you may not need to re-apply it, though it will disrupt animation (if you're using it) if you don't.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function(newVal){
  if(newVal) {
    // remove ng-hide to take the measurement
    angular.element(elem).removeClass('ng-hide');

    top = ($window.innerHeight - elem.outerHeight()) / 2;
    left = ($window.innerWidth - elem.outerWidth()) / 2;

    // optionally re-apply ng-hide here

    elem.css({ 'top': top, 'left': left });
  }
});
```